# Consulta SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no banco de dados em 2 tabelas e puxar os dados para pagina com uma condição seria essa se o id_noticia de uma tabela for igual o id da outra ao clicar na imagem ou nome vai redireciona para a pagina da noticia de acordo com o id porem ta dando certo gostaria de uma ajuda se possível

```
<?php    

 $pagCorrente = 1;
 if(isset($_GET['pag'])){
     $pagCorrente = (int)$_GET['pag'];
 }
 $mostrar = 10;

 $pagCorrente = $pagCorrente * $mostrar - $mostrar;

 $sqlTotal = "SELECT count(id) as total FROM noticia0;";     
 $ex = $conexao->query($sqlTotal);  
 $total = mysqli_fetch_object($ex);  
 $total = $total->total;

 $quantPages = ceil($total / $mostrar);

 $sql = "    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticia0 n, noticia nn
     WHERE n.id_noticia = nn.id   
     ORDER BY n.id desc LIMIT $pagCorrente,$mostrar";
 $wx = $conexao->query($sql);

 while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($wx)){

 ?>

<div class='div0'>
<a href="<?php echo SITE;?>noticia3.php?id=<?php echo $linha->id; ?>">
 <div class='pa'>
      <img src='<?php echo SITE . 'php/upload/' . $linha->imagen2;?>' />
  </div>

   <div class='po'>
   <p>
     <br><?php echo $linha->titulo;?></br>
     <br><?php echo $linha->sinopse;?></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua consulta, você está fazendo um `SELECT COUNT(*)`, é a unica coisa que está retornando em seu objeto, troque pelos seus alias `n.*`, `nn.*` que você terá o resultado de sua consulta. Se eu não tiver entendido muito bem, poste qual o erro está acontecendo.

Abs.

Comment: Já consegui resolver vlw man.